# Display correct values in fragment to fragment communication

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I am building a calculator with two fragments in Android Studio. One for the display and one for the buttons. The problem occurs when I try to ship the data to the view fragment. The buttons click but the view only displays some weird hexadecimal like info with the name of the fragment, then nothing else but the buttons are still audible when clicked. What would cause this? Could it be the view binding or possibly the way the fragments are set up?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FragmentDataCouple {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)



}

override fun dataCommunicator(editTextInput: String) {

    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("results", editTextInput)
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val upperFragment = DisplayFragment()
    upperFragment.arguments = intent.extras
    upperFragment.arguments = bundle
    transaction.add(R.id.topFragment, upperFragment).commit()
}
```

code in keyboard fragment

```
class KeyboardFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_keyboard) {

        private var _binding: FragmentKeyboardBinding? = null
        private val binding get() = _binding!!
        private lateinit var fragmentCouple: FragmentDataCouple

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            _binding = FragmentKeyboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val view = binding.root
            fragmentCouple = activity as FragmentDataCouple

            //On click listeners for numbers
            binding.btnZero.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnOne.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnTwo.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnThree.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnFour.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnFive.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnSix.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnSeven.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnEight.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            binding.btnNine.setOnClickListener { numberClicked() }
            
 fun numberClicked() {


     var btnClick = toString()

    when (view) {

        binding.btnZero ->{
            btnClick += "0"
        }
        binding.btnOne -> {
            btnClick += "1"
        }
        binding.btnTwo -> {
            btnClick += "2"
        }
        binding.btnThree -> {
            btnClick += "3"
        }
        binding.btnFour -> {
            btnClick += "4"
        }
        binding.btnFive -> {
            btnClick += "5"
        }
        binding.btnSix -> {
            btnClick += "6"
        }
        binding.btnSeven -> {
            btnClick += "7"
        }
        binding.btnEight -> {
            btnClick += "8"
        }
        binding.btnNine -> {
            btnClick += "9"
        }
        binding.posNeg ->{
            btnClick = "-$btnClick"
        }
    }
    fragmentCouple.dataCommunicator(btnClick)
}
```

code for display fragment

```
private var _binding: FragmentDisplayBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private lateinit var fragmentCouple: FragmentDataCouple
private var displayMath: String? = ""


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    _binding = FragmentDisplayBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    fragmentCouple = activity as FragmentDataCouple

    displayMath = arguments?.getString("results")
    binding.displayView.text = displayMath
    return view
}
```

Comment: Where do you have KeyboardFragment in your UI? Whenever a button is clicked you add a new DisplayFragment in the backstack. So, does KeyboardFragment hide when DisplayFragment is visible?

Comment: Both fragments stay visible inside fragment container views in activity.xml

Comment: So you are adding a new DisplayFragment to the backstack evertime a button is pressed. WHY?